# My browserified script won't run

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, browserify, reactjs

The javascript I write, after it is compiled using browserify through grunt, has no effect on the webpage whatsoever -- even console.log statements don't work, but it also reports no meaningful error in my javascript, even when I introduce it.
I have a Gruntfile.js that looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  //load plugins
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');

  //define tasks
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['all']);
  grunt.registerTask('all', ['clean', 'browserify:libs', 'browserify:app']);
  grunt.registerTask('server', ['all', 'watch:fast']);

  grunt.initConfig({
    //Watch the main.js file for changes
    watch: {
      fast: {
        files: 'src/frontend/main.js',
        tasks: ['browserify:app'],
        options: {
          livereload: true,
          nospawn: true
        }
      }
    },

    //Clean up any previous build artifacts
    clean: {
      build: ['/frontend/lib/*']
    },

    //Bundle stuff
    browserify: {
      options: {
        transform: [ ['reactify', {}], ['uglifyify', { 'global': true }] ]
        //bundleOptions: { 'debug': true } //for source map
      },
      //put all the libs into one file
      libs: {
        options: {
          require: ['socket.io', 'react']
        },
        src: "src/frontend/dummy_libs.js",
        dest: 'frontend/lib/libs.js'
      },
      //Compile the main.js file
      app: {
        options: {
          external: [
            'socket.io',
            'react'
          ]
        },
        src: 'src/frontend/main.js',
        dest: 'frontend/lib/main.js'
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Basically, what it does is it takes the socket.io and React libraries, and browserifies them into one file, lib/libs.js, and it take my main.js file and, with socket.io and react defined as external libraries for compilation speed, puts that through the reactify filter (it's a JSX file), minifies it, and then puts it into frontend/lib/main.js.

The main.js file is very simple, right now it has a couple test `console.log` statements, but none of these are showing up in the console, so I am stumped to how to make it work. All the console logs is:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/ [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 2ms]
Use of getUserData() or setUserData() is deprecated.  Use WeakMap or element.dataset instead. requestNotifier.js:63
GET http://localhost:8000/lib/libs.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1ms]
GET http://localhost:8000/lib/main.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1ms]
TypeError: mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create libs.js:858
TypeError: require.resolve is not a function libs.js:826
```

The Gruntfile runs with no errors, and I can read the frontend/libs/main.js, and it's properly minified and reactified.

Here's the main.js file, original:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var React = require('react');
var socket = require('socket.io')();

socket.on('depth:value', function(data) {console.log(data);});
socket.emit('test', 'was this sent succesfully?');
console.log('Test');
console.log('Test2');
console.log('Test3');

var Depth = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    socket.on('depth:value', this.newDepthValue);
    return { depth: 0 };
  },
  newDepthValue: function(data) {
    this.setState({ depth: data.depth });
    console.log('new state: { depth: ' + data.depth + ' }');
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>Depth: {this.state.depth}</div>
    );
  }
});

React.renderComponent(
  <Depth />,
  document.getElementById('depth')
);
```

And the compiled version:

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);throw new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'")}var f=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(f.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},f,f.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
var React=require("react"),socket=require("socket.io")();socket.on("depth:value",function(e){console.log(e)}),socket.emit("test","was this sent succesfully?"),console.log("Test"),console.log("Test2"),console.log("Test3");var Depth=React.createClass({displayName:"Depth",getInitialState:function(){return socket.on("depth:value",this.newDepthValue),{depth:0}},newDepthValue:function(e){this.setState({depth:e.depth}),console.log("new state: { depth: "+e.depth+" }")},render:function(){return React.DOM.div(null,"Depth: ",this.state.depth)}});React.renderComponent(Depth(null),document.getElementById("depth"));
//# sourceMappingURL=out.js.map

},{"react":"M6d2gk","socket.io":"KTyLuN"}]},{},[1])
```

I'm stumped, hopefully you guys can help me out. If you want more information, I would be happy to provide it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I should have done `require('socket.io-client')` instead. My mistake.